# Expression.Convert using type that isn't included

Tags: c#, lambda

So this is the Setup

You have a namespace DAL and a namespace DTO (In a different assembly). Both contain a class Foo.
What I was trying to do, is to specify EF includes on a DTO type and convert them to a DAL type.

We have the following collection coming from the front-end:

```
using DTO;

public class GetFooById : Request
{
    public GetFooById()
    {
        IncludeProperties = new HashSet<Expression<Func<object, object>>>
                    {
                        x  => ((Foo)x).Bar, //DTO.Foo, when debugging is DAL.Foo
                        x => ((Foo)x).Foobars,
                    };
    }
}
```

We use this collection in another assembly, something like this:

```
IQueryable<object> query = Context.Foos;

foreach (var expr in request.IncludeProperties)
{
        query = query.Include(expr);
}

var foo = query.First(x => x.Id == request.Id);
```

The strange part is, this code is compiling and executing, but the included properties are null.
When I'm debugging and hover over this part: `x  => ((Foo)x).Bar` The debugger says `Foo` is of type: DAL.Foo instead of the included DTO.Foo.

Is this because the expression is compiled in a file where we don't have an include to DTO, but we have an include to DAL? Isn't this a bug in c# ?

**Is this expected behavior in C# ?**

*Project framework is 4.0, but i'm compiling with 4.5 installed.*

Comment: What namespace is this type in? My guess is that it's *within* the DAL  namespace, so DAL.Foo is being picked up first. A short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem would make this simpler to diagnose.

Comment: Is GetFooById in a third assembly, or in the assembly of DAL or in the assembly of DTO? And in which namespace?

Answer (score 1):

This is not caused by C#. You're ignoring the result of `query.Include(expr);`, so the `Include` expression does not actually get applied anyway. As long as it remains unused, it cannot cause problems: even in regular C# code (without expression trees), if you've got an object of type `A`, then casting it to a completely distinct type `B` using `(B)(object)a` would obviously not work, but this would be detected at runtime, so only if the code actually gets called.

Also, Entity Framework does not currently support multiple types with the same name, as far as I am aware. It looks up types by name, and `DAL.Foo` and `DTO.Foo` have the same name. The type that EF knows about is the type that it ends up using. You should not rely on this.

Comment: See my edit, code still compiles, runs, but included properties are null. In my opinion this should throw an exception, or not compile.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts It cannot cause a compilation failure, because your use of `object` prevents any possible compile-time checks from being used. I'm surprised that your edited version does not throw an exception but does not work right either. I'll edit my answer to address that when I get a chance to check what EF does.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts In my testing, I've seen how `query.Include(expression)` gets translated to `query.Include("propertyName")`, and EF's checks only get applied after that. In other words, by the time EF sees it, the include argument is correct, and it should be expected that you get no exception. Do you have a concrete example where the include has no effect as you say?

Answer (score 0):

AS DAL.Foo is closer(*in current assembly*) than DTO.Foo (*in an included assembly*) hence the compiler picks it up first. It is expected and consistent behaviour, not a bug. You need to specify the name explicitly so, change this

```
x  => ((Foo)x).Bar,
```

to

```
 x  => ((DTO.Foo)x).Bar,
```

Comment: I know I can put the namespace in front. But my question is, is it expected behavior, that the expression is not using the included type?

Comment: AS DAL.Foo is closer than DTO.Foo hence the compiler picks it up. It is expected behaviour and consistent